# Automating a script in R

Tags: r, csv, automation

I need help in saving and rewriting values of a file(eg.csv) using R.I have a dataframe that has RMSE values of each models.

```
> v
     Er value
1 RMSE1   990
2 RMSE2  1000
3 RMSE3   991
4 RMSE4   983
5 RMSE5   987
6 RMSE6   657
> write.csv(v, file = "C:\\D_N\\Programs\\Energy Consumption\\v.csv")
```

I saved these values in csv formatted file called **v**. After a second process I have **new RMSE** values of those six models.

```
> v1
     Er Newvalue
1 RMSE1      889
2 RMSE2      890
3 RMSE3     1034
4 RMSE4      950
5 RMSE5      965
6 RMSE6      802
```

And everytime the process takes place, i will be getting a New RMSE Values. I am supposed to do an automation that gives me Mean values of RMSE. I know it is easy to do manually (to save up files everytime and add,divide to get mean value). But I want R to do it automatically.

Is it possible in R ? kindly suggests me some ideas. I believe the question is understandable.

Thank You.

Comment: You can save the versions of RMSE for each run in a R object. And when you run the new version, just load the saved R object, for last versions RMSE. This way you can automate the process in R, without having to use excel. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I even thought of doing like this. But the problem is, i will be having files counting 50 and more if i have to save and load it every time.  Thats not a good way of doing, i reckon.

Comment: You can import many files. A simple search on SO (or google) will yield many results for this. Once you have everything imported, you can calculate anything you wish on all datasets at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is my pseudo R code for your question. Please modify the code as per your needs. In my comment, I suggested to use lists. The advantage of using lists is that you do not need to save multiple files.

```
RMSE_VersionsFile <- "RMSE_VersionsFile.RData"
if(file.exists(RMSE_VersionsFile)) {
  load(RMSE_VersionsFile)
} else {
  RMSE_Versions <- list()
}

# Do your computation

#  .
#  .
#  .
#  .

# Calculate RMSE for the models, say it is RMSE
# Give a unique version name
# For example, version with time
library(dplyr)
versionName <- Sys.time() %>% gsub(":|-| ", "_", .)
RMSE_Versions[[versionName]] <- RMSE

# lapply on RMSE_Versions, to get the mean for RMSE for all versions, as per your need
save(RMSE_Versions, file=RMSE_VersionsFile, compress=TRUE) # Only one file required
```